# how to check if tar file is corrupted

Tags: linux, files, rhel, tar

I use the following cli in order to uncompressed tar file

```
tar xfz centos7-rpm.tar.gz -C /var/www/html
```

is it possible before uncompromising , to check the tar file - if tar file is corrupted or wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `tar` and `gzip` are independent operations you should check first if the compressed archive if OK:

```
gzip -t file.tar.gz
```

and after this (if OK) you must decompress the archive and test the tar archive:

```
gzip -dc  file.tar.gz|tar tvf -
```